# Home city and Visited City

Tags: logical-deduction

P, R, S, T, U and V are six colleagues who work for Fan Inc. headquartered at USA. Each of them lives in a different city that is one out of P, R, S, T, U and V, not necessarily in that order. Their organization has assigned each of them for a field visit in one of these six cities such that neither of them will be sent to the city where they live. The following points are known.

> — S will visit the city where T lives. — U will visit P. — V is from
>   T. — R and U will visit  each other's home city. — P's home city will
>   be visited by the person who lives in R. — The person from S will
>   visit T. — The initials of the name of each employee, his home city,
>   his visiting city and the name of the person who lives in that
>   visiting city are different.

Source : Me

Which city will V visit?
    S
    U
    R
    Cannot be determined

Please tell the approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- First step : create an empty grid with tree columns, people, habitation city and working city

  > ```
  >   people   |habitation city|working city
  >   ---------|---------------|------------ 
  >   P        |               |     
  >   R        |               |     
  >   S        |               |     
  >   T        |               |     
  >   U        |               |     
  >   V        |               |
  > ```

We can know fill the grid with statements

- Statement n°2 : "U will visit P."

  > simple statement
  >
  > ```
  >   people   |habitation city|working city
  >   ---------|---------------|------------ 
  >   P        |               |     
  >   R        |               |     
  >   S        |               |     
  >   T        |               |     
  >   U        |               |     
  >   V        |               |
  > ```
- Statement n°3 : "V is from T."

  > simple statement
  >
  > ```
  >   people   |habitation city|working city
  >   ---------|---------------|------------ 
  >   P        |               |     
  >   R        |               |     
  >   S        |               |     
  >   T        |               |     
  >   U        |               | P    
  >   V        | T             |
  > ```
- Statement n°4 : "R and U will visit each other's home city."

  > This means R's home city is U's working city
  >
  > ```
  >   people   |habitation city|working city
  >   ---------|---------------|------------ 
  >   P        |               |     
  >   R        | P             |     
  >   S        |               |     
  >   T        |               |     
  >   U        |               | P    
  >   V        | T             |
  > ```
- Statement n°7 : "The initials of the name of each employee, his home city, his visiting city and the name of the person who lives in that visiting city are different."

  > This means U's home city can't be P (already working city), R (the name of the person who lives in that visiting city), T (already used by V), and only leaves us S or V
  >
  > ```
  >   people   |habitation city|working city
  >   ---------|---------------|------------ 
  >   P        |               |     
  >   R        | P             |     
  >   S        |               |     
  >   T        |               |     
  >   U        | S/V           | P    
  >   V        | T             |
  > ```
- Statement n°6 : "The person from S will visit T."

  > As U already visit P, he can't be from S
  >
  > ```
  >   people   |habitation city|working city
  >   ---------|---------------|------------ 
  >   P        |               |     
  >   R        | P             |     
  >   S        |               |     
  >   T        |               |     
  >   U        | V             | P    
  >   V        | T             |
  > ```
- Statement n°4 : "R and U will visit each other's home city."

  > R visit V
  >
  > ```
  >   people   |habitation city|working city
  >   ---------|---------------|------------ 
  >   P        |               |     
  >   R        | P             | V   
  >   S        |               |     
  >   T        |               |     
  >   U        | V             | P    
  >   V        | T             |
  > ```
- Statement n°7 : "The initials of the name of each employee, his home city, his visiting city and the name of the person who lives in that visiting city are different."

  > Add all combinations
  >
  > ```
  >   people   |habitation city|working city
  >   ---------|---------------|------------ 
  >   P        | R/S/U         | R/S/T/U    
  >   R        | P             | V   
  >   S        | R/U           | R/T/U    
  >   T        | R/S/U         | R/S/U    
  >   U        | V             | P    
  >   V        | T             | R/S/U
  > ```
- Statement n°1 : "S will visit the city where T lives."

  > S can't visit T as T can't live in T, T can't live in S as S can't work in S
  >
  > ```
  >   people   |habitation city|working city
  >   ---------|---------------|------------ 
  >   P        | R/S/U         | R/S/T/U    
  >   R        | P             | V   
  >   S        | R/U           | R/U    
  >   T        | R/U           | R/S/U    
  >   U        | V             | P    
  >   V        | T             | R/S/U
  > ```
- Statement n°7 : "The initials of the name of each employee, his home city, his visiting city and the name of the person who lives in that visiting city are different."

  > S can't be the home city of S neither T, so S is the home city of P. P can't work at S anymore. Also, only P can work at T
  >
  > ```
  >   people   |habitation city|working city
  >   ---------|---------------|------------ 
  >   P        | S             | T   
  >   R        | P             | V   
  >   S        | R/U           | R/U    
  >   T        | R/U           | R/S/U    
  >   U        | V             | P    
  >   V        | T             | R/S/U
  > ```
- Statement n°5 : "P's home city will be visited by the person who lives in R."

  > P's home city is S. S can't work in S, that means T visit S and live in R. Therefore, S live in U
  >
  > ```
  >   people   |habitation city|working city
  >   ---------|---------------|------------ 
  >   P        | S             | T   
  >   R        | P             | V   
  >   S        | U             | R/U    
  >   T        | R             | S    
  >   U        | V             | P    
  >   V        | T             | R/U
  > ```
- Statement n°1 : "S will visit the city where T lives."

  > S will visit R
  >
  > ```
  >   people   |habitation city|working city
  >   ---------|---------------|------------ 
  >   P        | S             | T   
  >   R        | P             | V   
  >   S        | U             | R    
  >   T        | R             | S    
  >   U        | V             | P    
  >   V        | T             | U
  > ```

Final answer

> V will visit U

Comment: Great Reasoning and Explanation. Thanks for your effort. @kepotx